# Drop shadow with Angle using php GD

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

I am trying to create Shadow of an image using php GD after search a lot i never found any script that perform this on my images so i decided to write one for myself this is what i tried so far but when i run it generate an error

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Image\dropshadow.php on line 29
```

this is the complete code for better understanding

```
$gdimg = imagecreatefromjpeg('3.jpg');
 shadowImage($gdimg,12,2,'000000',215,10);

 function shadowImage($gdimg,$distance,$width,$hexcolor,$angle,$fade)
  {

  $width_shadow = cos(deg2rad($angle)) * ($distance + $width);
  $height_shadow = sin(deg2rad($angle)) * ($distance + $width);


  $imgX = imagesx($gdimg);
  $imgY = imagesy($gdimg);

  $offset['x'] = cos(deg2rad($angle)) * ($distance + $width - 1);
  $offset['y'] = sin(deg2rad($angle)) * ($distance + $width - 1);

  $tempImageWidth = $imgX + abs($offset['x']);
  $tempImageHeight = $imgY + abs($offset['y']);
  $gdimg_dropshadow_temp = imagecreatetruecolor($tempImageWidth, $tempImageHeight);
  imagealphablending($gdimg_dropshadow_temp,false);
  imagesavealpha($gdimg_dropshadow_temp,true);
  $transparent1 = imagecolorallocatealpha($gdimg_dropshadow_temp,0,0,0,127);
  imagefill($gdimg_dropshadow_temp,0,0,$transparent1);
  for ($x = 0; $x < $imgX; $x++) {
    for ($y = 0; $y < $imgY; $y++) {

        $colorat = imagecolorat($gdimg, $x, $y);
        $PixelMap[$x][$y] = imagecolorsforindex($gdimg, $colorat);
      }
  }

  /* Creates the shadow */
  $r = hexdec(substr($hexcolor, 0, 2));
  $g = hexdec(substr($hexcolor, 2, 2));
  $b = hexdec(substr($hexcolor, 4, 2));

  /* Essentially masks the original image and creates the shadow */
  for ($x = 0; $x < $tempImageWidth; $x++) {
    for ($y = 0; $y < $tempImageHeight; $y++) {
        if (!isset($PixelMap[$x][$y]['alpha']) ||
             ($PixelMap[$x][$y]['alpha'] > 0)) {

                if (isset($PixelMap[$x + $offset['x']][$y + $offset['y']]['alpha']) && ($PixelMap[$x + $offset['x']][$y + $offset['y']]['alpha'] < 127)) {
                    $thisColor = imagecolorallocatealpha($gdimg_dropshadow_temp ,$r, $g, $b, $PixelMap[$x + $offset['x']][$y + $offset['y']]['alpha']);
                    imagesetpixel($gdimg_dropshadow_temp, $x, $y, $thisColor);
                    }
                }
             }
        }

  /* Overlays the original image */
  imagealphablending($gdimg_dropshadow_temp,true);

  for ($x = 0; $x < $imgX; $x++) {
    for ($y = 0; $y < $imgY; $y++) {
        if ($PixelMap[$x][$y]['alpha'] < 127) {
            imagecolorallocatealpha($gdimg_dropshadow_temp, $PixelMap[$x][$y]['red'], $PixelMap[$x][$y]['green'], $PixelMap[$x][$y]['blue'], $PixelMap[$x][$y]['alpha']);
            imagesetpixel($gdimg_dropshadow_temp, $x, $y, $thisColor);
        }
    }
  }

  imagesavealpha($gdimg, true);
  imagealphablending($gdimg, false);

  // Merge the shadow and the original into the original.
  $src_w = imagesx($gdimg_dropshadow_temp);
  $src_h = imagesy($gdimg_dropshadow_temp);
  imagecopyresampled($gdimg, $gdimg_dropshadow_temp, 0, 0, 0, 0, $imgX, $imgY,$src_w,$src_h);

  imagejpeg($gdimg, "shadowImage.jpg");

  }
```

please make me correct. and tell me how can i create shadow of an image

Comment: can you give an example of what you want?

Comment: thanks for your replay kraysak . i am want to create something like that [link](http://jsfiddle.net/axtruo/5qV62/1/)

Comment: i am just want to create `box-shadow` alternative using php gd **"box-shadow": -22px -19px 9px 0px #FE0000**